# Sync of SYSVOL content between Windows 2016 Domain Controllers

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, replication, windows-server-2016, sysvol

I have the following setup:

- Two Domain Controllers in different sites (both Windows Server 2016)
  -The sites are permanently connected via a VPN (so the servers can directly reach each other)
- The Domain Controllers are in different subnets
- The Domain Controllers are both Global Catalogs

The problem I have is with the syncing/replication of SYSVOL content. It was syncing fine, but after the reboot of one of the servers it doesn't seem to sync/replicate anymore, while GPOs still sync/replicate without any problem.

Are there any ways to debug the replication of the SYSVOL content, or tools you would recommend to monitor the SYSVOL replication?

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that both servers are pointing to the same DNS?

Comment: `It was syncing fine, but after the reboot of one of the servers it doesn't seem to sync/replicate anymore, while GPOs still sync/replicate without any problem.` If GPO's are replicating, you need to tell us what is *not* replicating. There really should not be much in SYSVOL, except for some basic scripts.

Comment: Well I was trying to replicate a startup script.

Comment: `The problem I have is with the syncing/replication of SYSVOL content. It was syncing fine, but after the reboot of one of the servers it doesn't seem to sync/replicate anymore, while GPOs still sync/replicate without any problem.` - How are you determining this? What are you using to diagnose the problem? What is it that you're looking at?

Comment: @Fionn - Is [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659328/gpos-no-longer-sync-permissions-after-applying-kb4338814-to-server-2016) related?

Comment: Have you run dcdiag on each DC and verified the tests pass on both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Event log under Application and Services Log in event viewer it could be related to file replication service and the DC could be in one of the following states:

Assertions in the FRS service
Corruption of the local jet database
Journal wrap errors
FRS replication failures

This article might be able to help.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290762/using-the-burflags-registry-key-to-reinitialize-file-replication-servi